# PHP replace multiple values from an array to another one

Tags: php, arrays

I want to insert the values from the first array inside the second array, where the key's name is [cost]:

$newcosts

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 52.68
    [1] => 7414.68
    [2] => 2471.56
 )
```

$mainarray

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 2
    [date] => 15.12.2020
    [cost] => 60.00
    )
[1] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [date] => 22.12.2020
    [cost] => 60.00
    )
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 3
    [date] => 24.12.2020
    [cost] => 22.00
    )
```

I tried the following:

```
foreach ($mainarray as $key => $value) {
    $values[] = $value['cost'];
    $new_array[] = str_replace($values, $newcosts, $value);
}
```

for some reason, this is not showing the right data and sometime they get repeated. this is an example:

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 2
    [date] => 15.12.2020
    [cost] => 52.68
    )
[1] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [date] => 22.12.2020
    [cost] => 52.68
    )
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 3
    [date] => 24.12.2020
    [cost] => 2471.56
    )
```

Hope someone could help me on that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the mainarray's index to replace the `$newcosts` into the array.

```
foreach ($mainarray as $index => $subarray) {
    $mainarray[$index]['cost'] = $newcosts[$index];
}
```

Because you will have an unused variable `$subarray` this way, it would be nicer to use a for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mainarray); $i++) {
   $mainarray[$i]['cost'] = $newcosts[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

user [foreach](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_foreach.asp) to get value of $newcosts and then
in loop replace value of price by id
in foreach loop you shuld replace value of $mainarray

```
foreach($newcosts as $itme => $value){
 $mainarray [$itme ]['cost'] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using str_replace to replace float value ?

You can also index your array like this

```
for ($idx = 0; $idx <= count($mainarray); $idx++) {
     $mainarray[$idx]['cost'] = $mainarray[$idx];
}
```

edit : same solution as above